# Parametrised classes

Tags: class, haskell, parametrize

I have a class as follows:

```
class Token a where
    symbol :: a -> String
```

I also want all instances of `Token` to have a function `convert` which returns a parametrised type. The conversion alone works fine:

```
class Token a b where
    convert :: a -> b

data Egal = One | Two

instance Token Egal Int where
    convert One = 111
    convert Two = 222

main = print $ show (convert One :: Int)
```

But when I try to use both `symbol` and `convert` I get errors about ambiguity. This is my code:

```
class Token a b where
    convert :: a -> b
    symbol :: a -> String

data Egal = One | Two

instance Token Egal Int where
    convert One = 111
    convert Two = 222
    symbol One = "one"
    symbol Two = "two"

main = print $ show (convert One :: Int)
```

What am I doing wrong?

---

EDIT: Reading my own question I started wondering: Should these be two distinct classes and my `data Egal` show instanciate both?

Comment: Do you want every token to convert to only one type or to multiple types?

Comment: Perhaps you need `Token a b | a->b` (read up on functional dependencies).

Comment: @FyodorSoikin Thanks for your comment. To only one type. But that type is not known beforehand.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI Thanks. I will do some reading.

Comment: Can you add the error message the compiler gives? It helps make this question more discoverable.

Comment: The error message tells you exactly what language extension to enable.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As you have defined things here, you can have instances with the same `a` but conflicting `b`s. Like this:

```
instance Token Char Char where
    convert = id
    symbol c = [c]

instance Token Char Bool where
    convert = (>'m')
    symbol c = [c, c, c, c]
```

Now, should `symbol 'x'` be `"x"` or `"xxxx"`? Both are possible depending which of the above instances gets chosen; it is *ambiguous* which instance should be used for `symbol`, and therefore which answer you should get. There are various ways to fix this. One is to simply allow the ambiguity, and give yourself the ability to specify which instance to use at call sites. You can turn on the `AllowAmbiguousTypes` and `TypeApplications` extensions; then:

```
> symbol @_ @Char 'x' -- or, more explicitly, symbol @Char @Char 'x'
"x"
> symbol @_ @Bool 'x' -- explicitly, symbol @Char @Bool 'x'
"xxxx"
```

But in many cases, you really want the compiler to check that you haven't made multiple instances with conflicting `a`s. Then you can use either the `FunctionalDependencies` extension:

```
class Token a b | a -> b where
    convert :: a -> b
    symbol :: a -> String

instance Token Char Char where {- ... -}
```

or the `TypeFamilies` extension:

```
class Token a where
    type Conversion a
    convert :: a -> Conversion a
    symbol :: a -> String

instance Token Char where
    type Conversion Char = Char
    {- ... -}
```

They have more or less the same effect in most cases: conflicting instances are flagged, and there is no ambiguity left.

Answer (score 14):

In the comments, you wrote that a type `a` can only be converted to a single type `b`. Your current design allows to have many `b`s for the same `a`.

```
instance Token A B1 where
   convert = ...
   symbol = ...

instance Token A B2 where
   convert = ...
   symbol = ...
```

Why GHC complains? Above, both definitions of `symbol` have type `A -> String`, so GHC can't choose which instance to use from types only.

One (non ideal solution) is to enable the "ambiguous types" Haskell extension and choose the instance manually, every time `symbol` is called.

```
main = putStrLn $ symbol @A @B1 someAvalue
```

It would be better to instead tell Haskell that type `b` is determined from type `a` alone, so there's no ambiguity. This can be done using the functional dependencies extension, but in my opinion it's best achieved using the type families extension.

```
class Token a where              -- no b here
    type Converted a             -- the type after conversion
    convert :: a -> Converted a  -- we return that type
    symbol :: a -> String

data Egal = One | Two

instance Token Egal where
    type Converted Egal = Int   -- here we chose Int
    convert One = 111
    convert Two = 222
    symbol One = "one"
    symbol Two = "two"

main = print $ convert One -- no annotation needed
```